# Custom Tag Upload

Tags: docusignapi

I'm new to DocuSign and using the REST Api.
I have a template uploaded with a custom tag in it.  I have created a custom tag with an anchor.  For example ??sometagname??

I would like to then upload the value of this to be placed inside the template when sending an envelope based on the template.

1) Do I need to create a document from the envelope first?
2) What JSON structure do I use to send this up? I have tried many different variants based on documentation I have found online, but with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your create envelope call you can just add the "tabs" section and include you're specific tabs. On my template I have a checkbox, radio button group and text field. The Label cooresponds to what it's called on the template and then I am passing in the value (or selection in the checkbox/radiobutton cases).

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Some Document",
    "templateId": "xxxxxxxx-6A28-4257-8DAF-1FDDD5920289",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": "testemail@theemailtest.com",
        "tabs": {
            "checkboxTabs": [{
                "name": "Checkbox",
                "tabLabel": "TheCheckbox",
                "selected": "true"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "value": "Green!",
                "tabLabel": "FavoriteColor?"
            }],
                "radioGroupTabs": [{
                    "groupName": "Radio",
                    "radios": [{
                      "value": "Yes",
                      "selected": "true"
                    }, {
                      "value": "No",
                      "selected": "false"
                    }]
            }]
        },
        "name": "Signer 1test",
        "roleName": "sender"
    }]
}
```

This will tick the checkbox, choose the Yes radio selection, and fill the FavoriteColor? data field as "Green!"

Comment: I've placed a textbox in with the tabLabel as described with FavoriteColor? and it is not replaced when I send this JSON up to the template.  Email is sent to recipient correctly, text is not replaced though, nor is the checkbox checked